spring boot upgrade causing application ApplicationContext failed
I have a spring boot app in 1.5.X which recently I updated with 2.7.18. After that update post running my service Tests I am getting below issue
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'elasticsearchHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Beans must not be empty

I am using below dependencies along with smoe other third party libs.
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
implementation("org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.6.1")

Any idea why I am getting this exception. BTW, I do not want to upgrade Elasticsearch dependency.

going from version 1.5 to 2.7 is a huge step- You may fix this one issue and fall into the next. Try smaller increments. Keep on incrementing the version until it breaks. Check the release notes of the breaking version for a potential smoking gun
